# Getting 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed' error while running pandas.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas

```
training_data = pd.get_dummies(train_data_df,columns=["Pclass","Sex","Embarked"])
```

These three columns are categorical features while running  the above I am getting the error:

```
'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed'
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to SO; for the next time, please spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time). Also, this is a standard pandas question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Tell us about `train_data_df`

Comment: Can you show us `train_data_df.info()`?

Comment: I have got the issue, actually one of the columns is of 'object class' that's why it is not able to produce dummies of the column.